# Can Windows Sharepoint Foundation 2010 be installed on Windows Server 2008 R2 Foundation?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, sharepoint-2010

I think the question is quite straightforward; is it possible, has anyone tried it, or does anyone know of any issues encountered when doing it?

Thanks,

Yusuf

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, see here for more information:
[Windows Server 2008 R2 Foundation](http://www.microsoft.com/oem/en/products/servers/pages/windows_server_2008_r2_foundation.aspx)